# Residue field on $\mathrm{spec} ( \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a field, and $X$ a regular projective curve over $\mathrm{Spec} ( K)$. For any closed point $x$ we have a residue field, denoted $\kappa(x)$, which is a finite extension of my ground field $K$. And we denote $[\kappa(x):K]$ the residue degree on $x$.

Now let consider $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb(Z)$, the closed points are the prime numbers $p$, which have for residue field the field $\mathbb{F}_p$. Do we have an analogue of the residue degree on the prime $p$ ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Since $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ doesn't live over a field, there is no literal analogue. On the other hand, there's a common analogy made between $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p[T])$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, and it suggests that in principle you can pretend that $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a "curve over $\mathbb{F}_1$" (which can be a useful perspective and people do exploit this) even though this isn't literally true in any reasonable sense.

Comment: @AshwinIyengar The magic field called [$\mathbb F_{\text{un}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the residue degree of a closed point $x \in \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb F_q[T])$ is $\log_q |\kappa(x)|$.  In $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$ we have no fixed prime power $q$, so it's natural (no pun intended) to define the residue degree of $x \in \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$ as the natural logarithm of $|\kappa(x)|$; that is, the point $[p]$ has degree $\log p$.

This is actually a standard idea in Arakelov theory.  Namely, define an *Arakelov divisor* on $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$ to be a pair $(D, g)$, where $D = (n_p)_{p \text{ prime}}$ is a divisor on $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$, and $g$ is a real number which we view as encoding data at the archimedean place of $\mathbb Z$.  Just as a nonzero rational function on a curve induces a divisor, a nonzero rational number $a$ induces an Arakelov divisor
$$\widehat{\mathrm{div}}(a) := (\mathrm{div}(a), -\log |a|).$$
Then, just as one can take the degree of a divisor on a curve, there is a notion of the arithmetic degree of an Arakelov divisor:
$$\widehat{\mathrm{deg}}(D, g) := g + \sum_p n_p \cdot \log p.$$
Here the $\log p$ factor plays the role of the usual degree of a point (of a curve over a field).  You can check that every principal Arakelov divisor (i.e. each $\widehat{\mathrm{div}}(a)$ for $a \in \mathbb Q^{\times}$) has arithmetic degree zero.  This is analogous to the fact that a rational function on an algebraic curve has as many zeroes as poles (counted with multiplicity).  It's an early instance of the philosophy that the nonarchimedean place gives a "completion" of the affine curve $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$.

Reference for the Arakelov theory:  section 1.2.B of [Chambert-Loir](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eantoine.chambert-loir/enseignement/2008-09/cga/cga.pdf).

Comment: I'm curious: are there any situations where the actual real number value of $\log p$ is useful in this context, rather than just considering it as some kind of formal value?

Comment: @EricWofsey Great question, which unfortunately I'll have to leave to the experts.  Certainly for what I've said it's good enough to work consistently with $\log_b$ for any fixed base $b > 1$.